# Unity Build with OpenXR enabled fails

Tags: unity-game-engine, gitlab-ci, openxr

Our Project is build on a gitlab-runner on linux using a docker image based on

```
unityci/editor:ubuntu-2021.2.7f1-windows-mono-3
```

We switched the project to OpenXR recently (com.unity.xr.openxr).
Now a clean build fails with

> The only standalone targets supported are Windows x64 and OSX with OpenXR.
> Other architectures and operating systems are not supported at this time.

Now CI builds with the old cache still run.
We definitely run

```
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer
```

with

```
target = BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64
```

I have no further ideas how to approach this problem and any hint towards a path to a solution is welcome.